# Query a big query table using a geojson input

Tags: google-bigquery, geospatial

I have a BigQuery table with data. The metadata table have two columns one is latitude and other is longitude. How can I query this table with a custom geojson that I have to filter only those rows which fall inside the geojson.

Answer (score 0):

do you need something like this?

```
declare filter string;
set filter = '{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [...]}';

select ...
where st_intersect(
  st_geogpoint(longitude_column, latitude_column)), 
  st_geogfromgeojson(filter))
```

Note that this might be slow if you have a lot of data. If you have more than a few gigabytes, consider creating actual Geography-typed column and clustering the table on this column. Then the query like above will use spatial index and will be faster.